# is use ubuntu juju sync-tools for openstack need bootstrap before?

Tags: json, ubuntu, juju

I am use juju in my openstack environment .

After reading docs about juju , I know that , I need generate-image and generate tools for prepareation .

So , below is my steps:

1. glance image-create   .... ; this step works well and give out an image ID
2. juju metadata generate-image  ... -d ./jujuopenstack ; this step works well
3. juju metadata generate-tools .. -d ./jujuopenstack ; this step works well
4. juju  sync-tools  --source="https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools"   --debug  --show-log

   this step FAILED ! and tell me that I NEED bootstrap openstack environment .
5. ( I have no choice but to bootstrap my environment  )

   juju bootstrap --debug --metadata-source /home/john/juju  -v --show-log --upload-tools

   this step will lanch a new instance , and can ssh into it . 
   the log is :
   ... ...
   Running apt-get update
   Running apt-get upgrade
   Installing package: curl
   Installing package: cpu-checker
   Installing package: bridge-utils
   Installing package: rsyslog-gnutls
   Bootstrapping Juju machine agent
   ... ....

juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:465

```
      fetchData failed for "http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/streams/v1/mirrors.json": cannot find URL "http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/streams/v1/mirrors.json" not found
```

juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:542 
no mirror index file found

juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:428 
read metadata index at "http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/streams/v1/index.json"

juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:432

skipping index because of error getting latest metadata "http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/streams/v1/index.json": index file has no data for cloud {regionOne htxxxxxx.0.33:5000/v2.0/} not found

juju.cmd supercommand.go:323 
      cannot set initial environ constraints: index file has no data for cloud {regionOne httxxxxxx7.0.33:5000/v2.0/} not found
juju.cmd supercommand.go:323 
    failed to bootstrap environment: subprocess encountered error code 1

............

==============================================================

I have no choice , then rerun sync-tools

juju  sync-tools  --source="htxxxxxxstreams.canonical.com/juju/tools"   --debug  --show-log

but told me that :

error dialing "wssxxxxx72.27.0.50:17070/", will retry: websocket.Dial wss://172.27.0.50:17070/: dial tcp 172.27.0.50:17070: connection refused

===================

What I want to know and make clear is , do we need bootstrap before using sync-tools ?

thanks in advance .